# JaxB transforming empty element into null when unmarshalling

Tags: jaxb, cxf, wsdl2java, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have a WSDl element something like :

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="listElement" nillable="true" type="tns:test"></xs:element>
```

in the SOAP request if i send empty element for listElement like :

```
<listElement/>
```

Then JaxB is creating something like :

```
listElement= new Arraylist<Test>();
listElement.add(new Test());
```

So i am getting listElement as a single arrayed with Test Object.

I want to do something which can set the listElement to Null when empty element is passed. I can 't use @XMLJavaAdapter annotation's because this is contract first and all the input objects are generated one.

I need to add some kind of binding at WSDL level or to Generation level.

Any Help will be highly APPRECIATED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `listElement` element really represents null then it should be sent as follows:

```xml
<listElement xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

Doing any sort of special handling is ultimately going to cause you trouble.

Comment: Hi Blaise, i don't have the handle on client is there any way i could do some sort of modification once i receive the content on the service side?